# Wpf Xaml change canvas property "Path.Fill"

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a scenario. I have my custom vector logo which I defined in separate xaml file MyLogo.xaml. I also added default fill color.

now when I run my app, I want to change it's color depending on enum value, but somehow it does not change... Can someone please help me?

this is the xaml of my logo and triggers declaration:

```
<misc:MyLogo
    DockPanel.Dock="Top"
    Height="200"
    Margin="0 30 0 0">
    <misc:MyLogo.Style>
        <Style>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding MyEnum}" Value="{x:Static enum:MyEnum.ValueOne}">
                    <Setter Property="Path.Fill" Value="#FFFFFF" />
                </DataTrigger>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding MyEnum}" Value="{x:Static enum:MyEnum.ValueTwo}">
                    <Setter Property="Path.Fill" Value="#000000" />
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </misc:MyLogo.Style>
</misc:MyLogo>
```

If it helps I'm using Caliburn Micro. So please can you tell me where is the bug, o what kind of workaround are there?

I tried [How to change a path fill (on a button) with triggers in XAML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14562186/how-to-change-a-path-fill-on-a-button-with-triggers-in-xaml/14562868) solution but it didn't helped...

**UPDATE 1**

MyLogo.xaml

As you can see Path has it's default Fill value:

```
<Viewbox xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" Stretch="Uniform">
    <Canvas Name="svg4" Width="10" Height="9">
        <Canvas.RenderTransform>
            <TranslateTransform X="0" Y="0"/>
        </Canvas.RenderTransform>
        <Canvas.Resources/>
        <Path xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" Name="path2" Fill="#FFFFFFFF">
            <Path.Data>
                <PathGeometry Figures="M10 4.194v.612H1.195L5.049 8.57l-.44.43L0 4.5 4.608 0l.441.43-3.854 3.764z" FillRule="EvenOdd"/>
            </Path.Data>
        </Path>
    </Canvas>
</Viewbox>
```

**UPDATE 2 (PROBLEM ANSWER)**
After some research i finally managed to fix my problem... So if anyone will face this, the simplest solution is this:

1. As in comments some users wrote me that I should remove Viewbox and Canvas elements from my xaml then you can leave it (in my scenario it is auto generated xaml file from svg if it's generated then it should be valid like it is)
2. To change the color of my logo, I had to create Dependency Property for my xaml. It looks like this:

   ```
   public partial class MyLogo: UserControl
   {
       public static readonly DependencyProperty BackgroundFillProperty =
           DependencyProperty.Register("BackgroundFill", typeof(SolidColorBrush), typeof(MyLogo), new PropertyMetadata(new SolidColorBrush()));

   public MyLogo() => InitializeComponent();

   public SolidColorBrush BackgroundFill
   {
       get => (SolidColorBrush)GetValue(BackgroundFillProperty);
       set => SetValue(BackgroundFillProperty, value);
   }
   ```

   }

Then in MyLogo.xaml I changed my Fill property with the following:

```
 Fill="{Binding BackgroundFill, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}}"
```

and finally in my view where the triggers are, I changed setters to this:

```
<Setter Property="misc:MyLogo.BackgroundFill" Value="#ffffff" />
```

And that's it.. Hope someone will find this useful :)

Comment: how did you added the default fill? could you add the `<misc:MyLogo>` to the post please?

Comment: @X39 Updated my question

Comment: instead of setting the attribute in the path, use a default style. That should do the trick

Comment: @X39 what do you mean by using default style?

Comment: Besides the problem in the duplicate question, your MyLogo seems to be a Viewbox, not a Path. However, you can't set `Path.Fill` on Viewbox. Your approach won't work.

Comment: @NikasŽalias `<Path.Style>...</Path.Style>`

Comment: @X39 you approach does not work

Comment: @Clemens then any solutions for my problem?

Comment: @NikasŽalias there is also the problem Clemens pointed out, it might be solvable by binding with realtive target to first parent of type Viewbox

Comment: @X39 I removed Viewbox tags, but nothing happened

Comment: Use the Path without Viewbox and Canvas. Both seem redundant, since there are no other child elements in the Canvas, and a Path can stretch by itself.

Comment: I left only the path tag in xaml, removed viewbox and canvas tags. Still can't change the color

Comment: Did you also replace `Fill="#FFFFFFFF"` by a Style Setter?

Comment: @Clemens I done it both ways, with style setter and without

Comment: Hard to tell. Probably edit your question with what you have right now. Or ask a new question.